# Intellij scratch files - how to delete them?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

I have created a few scratch files in android studio (fork of Intellij). by going to tools-->new scratch file.

But now i have soo many scratch files and i dont know how to delete them since they auto save. Can anyone help ?

Some info: scratch files are used to prototype code without it actually mingling with your exisiting code. Its like a notepad which auto saves.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To delete a scratch file or buffer, follow these steps:

1. Switch to the Scratches view of the Project tool window.
2. Under the Scratches pseudo-folder, right-click the scratch to be deleted, and choose Delete on the context menu.
3. Confirm deletion.

Source:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/scratches.html?origin=old_help#d640596e253

I was also able to do it by pressing cmd+E (for mac) to open the recent files popup. Then select the line and hit the delete key.

Comment: Is it possible to delete a scratch file that is being edited without opening the Scratches View? Possibly with some keys binding/shortcut?
I do not see the edited scratch file in Recent Files (Ctrl + E) nor Recently Edited Files (Ctrl + Shift + E).

Comment: Alt+Home opens files in current location, then select file (if not highlighted already) with Up/Down and press Del.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Switch to the Scratches view of the Project tool window.]

1. Switch to the Scratches view of the Project tool window.
2. Under the Scratches pseudo-folder, right-click the scratch to be deleted, and choose 
   Delete on the context menu.
3. Confirm deletion.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to have the file deleted automatically by clearing the content before the tab is closed:

> IntelliJ IDEA numbers scratch files sequentially starting from 1. If
> you close a tab with an empty scratch file, IntelliJ IDEA deletes it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html#create-scratch-buffer

Comment: Not obvious when you're staring at the scratch file in IntelliJ! TY!

Comment: No, that functionality is not very obvious :-) @davidbak